# Android adding views calculating the angle with one another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

[image]

In this above picture, all circle is a view with three text view. These views will be added dynamically. It will be 4 to 15

And at the below circle view with three text view will be fixed. 
All circle will be connected with the end one. and will need to draw a line with one another. And at the middle of the line there will also be a `textview`.

How to implement this custom view. Any kind of will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be possible by calculating and drawing all the elements separately, such as `canvas.drawLine`, `canvas.drawCircle` and `canvas.drawText`. However it doesn't seem like there is enough room for 15 elements on your page. Should it be arranged in a semi-circle, a full circle, or would a grid view be better suited?

Comment: I have drawn semi circle. I am afraid I will not be able to add 15 items